# how to fetch data from SELECT query to a <select> as a <option>

Tags: javascript, html, sql, node.js, ajax

i've just find out how to fetch data from database with this code in my server side javascript (index.js);

```
con.connect(function(err) {
con.query("SELECT Cliente FROM Tab_Clienti;", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
    });
});
```

and this is part of the output:

```
RowDataPacket { Cliente: 'GALLERIA DELL ACCADEMIA DI FIRENZE AUDIO - VIDEO'},
RowDataPacket { Cliente: 'ZETEMA AUDIO - VIDEO' },
RowDataPacket { Cliente: 'TERRE DES HOMMES AUDIO - VIDEO' },
RowDataPacket { Cliente: 'ISMETT AUDIO - VIDEO' },
RowDataPacket { Cliente: 'PRAGMATIKA AUDIO - VIDEO' },
RowDataPacket { Cliente: 'CANTINA DI SOAVE AUDIO - VIDEO' },
```

how do i get those info and put into my workspace.html, each data needs to be insert into a  tag, like below:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="clienti">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
</select>
```

my client side file is called app.js just for info.

Comment: have you fetched this data using ajax? is it available to your client?
what have you tried?

Comment: yes i do have ajax, and i still haven't tried anything cause i have no idea what should i do, i just know that i have the row result to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that your data reaches the client via ajax and is an array :
in your ajax success function :

```
success : function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        $("#clienti").append($("<option>"+response[i]["Cliente"]+"</option>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: i got a json at localhost/Clienti with the data of my query how i put it in <select>

Comment: are you having problems getting the json from your backend?

Comment: ok right now i got my /Clienti file json with all the data that i need, but now i need to put it in the <select> tag

Comment: yes but is there any code before? cause it gives me an error

Comment: you will need to open another question for that.

Comment: ok actually i've found the missing part of the code i needed, i used your code and it seems to work cause it populate my <select>, the  problem now is that is populated with undefined object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168396/discussion-between-gargantua-and-aniruddha-gohad).